# SQL ORDER BY two columns, whichever is higher

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that looks like so

```
ITEM_NAME     | NUM_SOLD | NUM_VIEWS
Apple         |       50 |        75
Orange        |       40 |        85
Pear          |       80 |        70
Cherry        |       15 |        60
```

I want to sort this by whichever number is highest in **either** of the last two columns.

So the above table would be sorted like so:

```
ITEM_NAME     | NUM_SOLD | NUM_VIEWS
Orange        |       40 |        85
Pear          |       80 |        70
Apple         |       50 |        75
Cherry        |       15 |        60
```

You can see that by the numbers I punched in, they're mostly sorted by `NUM_VIEWS`, but because `Pear` has a higher `NUM_SOLD` value than either of `Apple`'s values, it gets sorted between `Orange` and `Apple`.

This Apple and Pear example is what I can't get to work properly.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
ORDER BY GREATEST(num_sold, num_views)
```

(See [`GREATEST(value1,value2,...)` in §12.3.2 "Comparison Functions and Operators" of the *MySQL 5.6 Reference Manual*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest).)

Comment: Thank you!  Well, it's `GREATEST(num_sold, num_views) DESC` for what I posted but thanks!  I messed with groups and order bys for so long! lol

Answer (score 4):

```
order by
case when num_sold>num_views 
     then num_sold 
     else num_views 
end
```

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned by other users, using the GREATEST function is the most appropriate. I would add, however that you may need to COALESCE ([mysql coalesce() docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce)) your values with zero if your columns default to NULL or could ever contain a NULL value.

This is because **GREATEST will return NULL if any value passed is NULL** ([mysql greatest() docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest)), and therefore affect your ORDER BY clause by pushing all those with NULL values in either column to the bottom of your descending order.

If your counts have a *zero* default then it will be fine but if they are null by default or you require this method for any other table with null values, then this will be required. It caught me out when working with dates which often have NULL defaults.

```
ORDER BY GREATEST(
    COALESCE(NUM_SOLD, 0),  # returns the column value or zero if null
    COALESCE(NUM_VIEWS, 0)
)
```

*Note: I don't have enough points to put this in a comment but I figured it was valuable enough for an answer.*

Answer (score 0):

I would generally do with with an IF statement

```
IF @a > @b
BEGIN
  SELECT Col1, Col2, ... FROM Table1 Where... ORDER BY Col1
END
ELSE
BEGIN
  SELECT Col1, Col2, ... FROM Table1 Where... ORDER BY Col2
END
```